# How to transform List<X> to another List<Y>

Tags: java, list, transform, guava

I have two lists of objects; `List<X>` and `List<Y>`. `X` and `Y` are ojects that look like:

```
public class X {
    String a;
    String b;
    String v;
    String w;
    String m;
    String n;
}

public class Y {
    String a;
    String b;
    List<A> aList;
}
public class A {
    String v;
    String w;
    List<B> bList;
}
public class B {
    String m;
    String n;
}
```

How transform `List<X>` into `List<Y>` based on a rule:
Some fields' values must be equal.
For example:
In `List<Y>`, for one object Y, field a's value must equal.
In Y's field `List<A>`, for one object A, field w's value must equal.
In A's field `List<B>`, for one object B, field m's value must equal and so on.

Guava has this method, [Lists#transform](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), but I don't know how to transform.

Or any other way?

Comment: 1) You said "field a's value must equal"? Equal to what? 2) What happens if these conditions aren't met?

Comment: I do not think there is any build in function for this level of transformation . You will just have to loop and check yourself.

Comment: "field a's value must equal", as List<X> to List<Y>, X's field a must equal Y's field a, X's field w must equal A's field w in object Y and so on... And condition couldn't met, because if a is null, just a new Y with the null filed a.

Comment: Still not making sense. You have `List<A>` in `Y`, how many `A` objects is this list supposed to have? And if it's more than one, do they all just take the same values?

Comment: Ok, Let's make it more easier to understand. X is a table in database, and I want transform it into three tables, the table's relationship is like Y. I use hibernate. This is the primary key and foreign key relationship. because I can not design the table, some column in table A maybe change in B or Y, so I want to a function level for this transform, if something change, it's easy rebuild and   re-grouping.

Answer (score 77):

```
public static <F,T> List<T> transform(List<F> fromList,
                                      Function<? super F,? extends T> function
```

You might want to read up the API docs for [Lists.transform()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) and [Function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html), but basically the caller of the transform provides a `Function` object that converts an `F` to a `T`.

For example if you have a `List<Integer> intList` and you want to create a `List<String>` such that each element of the latter contains the english representation of that number (1 becomes "one" etc) and you have a access to a class such as [IntToEnglish](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3685) then

```
Function<Integer, String> intToEnglish = 
    new Function<Integer,String>() { 
        public String apply(Integer i) { return new IntToEnglish().english_number(i); }
    };

List<String> wordsList = Lists.transform(intList, intToEnglish);
```

Does that conversion.

You can apply the same pattern to transform your `List<X>` to `List<Y>`

Comment: Not sure if solves the issue but very impressive

Comment: Which api doc are you referring to?

Comment: @Java Ka Baby I mean the docs at http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries. Google collections API is awesome. Jon Skeet also referred it in your recent question.

Comment: Ok thanks Guava seems popular these days have never used it directly will read up :) cheers

Comment: Here's an interesting gotcha to be aware of: transform returns a *view* of the original list, which is *still* linked to the original list, and not a separate new list. I.e. if you remove an element from the list returned from transform, it will also remove the element from the original list. Just caught me out, so thought I'd share :)

Comment: BE AWARE - Lists.transform() is LAZY! From Guava JavaDoc: Note: serializing the returned list is implemented by serializing fromList, its contents, and function -- not by serializing the transformed values. This can lead to surprising behavior, so serializing the returned list is not recommended. Instead, copy the list using ImmutableList.copyOf(Collection) (for example), then serialize the copy. Other methods similar to this do not implement serialization at all for this reason.

Comment: @vellotis and stephendnicholas, your comments must be included into this answer in UPPERCASE. Really, this is not obvious behavior at all.

Comment: This was very useful in my scenario to transform role Entity into role DTO.

Comment: As others mentioned - be aware of Lists.transform! Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63754218/1694265 I pasted a snippet showing how it may surprise you.

Answer (score 17):

With java lambda:

```
public static <K,V,Q extends K> List<V> transform( final List<Q> input, final java.util.function.Function<K,V> tfunc ) {
    if( null == input ) {
        return null;
    }
    return input.stream().map(tfunc).collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
```

You just need to implement:
    java.util.function.Function

Comment: This is nice. Using Java API without need to install Guice.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class GuavaTransform {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<X> xList = new ArrayList<X>();
        xList.add(new X("a", "b", "v", "w", "m", "n"));
        xList.add(new X("a1", "b1", "v1", "w1", "m1", "n1"));
        for(X elem: xList) {
            System.out.println("An instance of X:"+ elem);
        }
        System.out.println();
        List<Y> yList = Lists.transform(xList, new TransformXY());
        for(Y elem: yList) {
            System.out.println("The corresponding instance of Y: \n"+elem);
        }
    }
}

class TransformXY implements Function<X, Y> {

    @Override
    public Y apply(X x) {
        List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
        bList.add(new B(x.m, x.n));
        List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
        aList.add(new A(x.v, x.w, bList));
        return new Y(x.a, x.b, aList);
    }
}

class X {
    String a;
    String b;
    String v;
    String w;
    String m;
    String n;
    X(String a, String b, String v, String w, String m, String n) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("(");
        sb.append(a+",");
        sb.append(b+",");
        sb.append(v+",");
        sb.append(w+",");
        sb.append(m+",");
        sb.append(n);
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
class Y {
    String a;
    String b;
    List<A> aList;
    Y(String a, String b, List<A> aList) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.aList = aList;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(a+"\n");
        sb.append(b+"\n");
        for(A elem: aList) {
            sb.append(elem+"\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } 
}
class A {
    String v;
    String w;
    List<B> bList;
    A(String v, String w, List<B> bList) {
        super();
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
        this.bList = bList;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("--------"+v+"\n");
        sb.append("--------"+w+"\n");
        for(B elem: bList) {
            sb.append(elem+"\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
class B {
    String m;
    String n;
    B(String m, String n) {
        super();
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("----------------"+m+"\n");
        sb.append("----------------"+n+"\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
An instance of X:(a,b,v,w,m,n)
An instance of X:(a1,b1,v1,w1,m1,n1)

The corresponding instance of Y: 
a
b
--------v
--------w
----------------m
----------------n



The corresponding instance of Y: 
a1
b1
--------v1
--------w1
----------------m1
----------------n1
```

Comment: +1 for "Guava", explaining with fruits is the best idea.

Answer (score 5):

Same as @Isaace but with the lambda syntax (got it from [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/)):

```
List<X> xList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Y> yList = xList
        .stream()
        .map(n -> someTransformFunc(n))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 style, IntelliJ IDEA‎ helped me out:

```
List<X> xList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Y> yList = xList
        .stream()
        .map(X::getY)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

assume have two object can interconversion, Coach and EntityBase

1.declare generic method

```
   public static <TSourse, TResult> void ToList(List<TSourse> list, List<TResult> results) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        for (TSourse obj : list) {
            TResult tResult = (TResult) obj;
            if (tResult == null) {
                throw new AppException("error....");
            }
            results.add(tResult);
        }
    }
}
```

2.call this method

```
  List<EntityBase> entityBaseList = new ArrayList<>();
    Coach coach = new Coach();
    coach.setId("123");
    entityBaseList.add(coach);

    List<Coach> coachList = new ArrayList<>();
    ToList(entityBaseList, coachList);
    //will complete List<AObj> to another List<BObj>
```