# Orika - list to list conversion

Tags: java, orika

This is probably an easy one, but I cant find it in the docs.
I have a person class

```
class BasicPerson {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private Date birthDate;
   // getters/setters omitted
}
```

and a list of it

```
ArrayList<Person>
```

I want to change them to change them to

```
ArrayList<PersonDTO>
```

but with out an explicit loop. 
Is there a way to use MapperFacade.map for a list to list one line conversion ?

Comment: You could you Guava and Lists.transform.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383624/how-to-transform-listx-to-another-listy)

Comment: Thanks. But orika is byte code handled which seems faster.

Comment: Plus I find it hard to use a framework or library with this at the top of its site https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained   -   "Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code. These are by far the most easily (and most commonly) abused parts of Guava, and when you go to preposterous lengths to make your code "a one-liner," the Guava team weeps"

Answer (score 16):

It has this functionality built-in. Did you tried using the method

`List<D> ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper.mapAsList(Iterable<S> source, Class<D> destinationClass)`?

I tried to find a updated version of the Javadoc, but here is one of the 1.3.5. The current version is 1.4.5.
[MapperFacade Class](http://javadox.com/ma.glasnost.orika/orika-core/1.3.5/ma/glasnost/orika/MapperFacade.html)

Comment: Yup the above answer is correct. You can just use 
`return mapper.mapAsList(basicPerson, PersonDTO.class);` 
Should be accepted.

Comment: It converts the date to `longValue` instead of giving it a proper date format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141817/date-format-is-changing-in-dto-but-not-in-listdto-on-returning-through-respon

Comment: Given the question nature, you linked, this has nothing to do with Orika, but with Jackson. As I far as I can tell, successfully mapping the source to the destination class.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `MapperFacade` interface, Orika can perform the [mapping multiple times](http://www.javabyexamples.com/mapping-collections-using-orika#run-mapper-on-collections) on the collection:

```
final MapperFacade mapperFacade = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
final List<Person> people = // Get the person instances
final List<PersonDto> personDtos = mapperFacade.mapAsList(people, PersonDto.class);
```

On the other hand, if you use the `BoundMapperFacade` interface, it doesn't contain such a convenience method.

And lastly, if you choose to use the `ConfigurableMapper` approach, it also includes a `mapAsList` method which in fact delegates to the `MapperFacade.mapAsList` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.miya.takeaway.common.util.orika;

import com.miya.takeaway.common.util.orika.converter.ConverterHelper;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.converter.ConverterFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OrikaUtils {

    private static MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();


    public static <T> List<T> map(List<?> objects, Class<T> target) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(objects)) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade().mapAsList(objects.toArray(), target);
    }
}
```

Comment: add some explanation to the answer IN THE ANSWER