# Creating a new collection from an existing collection

Tags: java, guava

I have a collection of objects as follows:

```
Collection<Foo>
```

where `Foo` is

```
public class Foo {

    private User user;
    private Item item;

    public Foo(User user, Item item) {
        this.user = user;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

I want to return another collection of type `Collection<Item>` using `Collection<Foo>`. I could do this by using a `for loop` and looping through Collection, getting the item, and adding it to a new list. So far I have used Google Guava to create my `Collection<Foo>` using a predicate.

Is there a method/function in Google guava which will allow me to create a `Collection<Item>` from `Collection<Foo>`? Should I use the transform function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use Java 8:

```
Collection<Item> items = foos.stream()
            .map(Foo::getItem)
            .collect(toList());
```

Otherwise you can indeed [use the transform method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383831/829571). In your case:

```
Function<Foo, Item> f = 
    new Function<Foo, Item>() { 
        public Item apply(Foo foo) { return foo.getItem(); }
    };

Collection<Item> items = Collections2.transform(foos, f);
```

Comment: could you give an alternative solution if Java 8 is not an option?

Comment: Note that if you use `transform`, the result is a _live view_ of the original collection. That's different than using the Java 8 method or looping, as both of those return a new collection that doesn't change when you change the original. You can always copy that view into a new collection if you need that though.