# Create array of string from an Arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

I want to get :

```
String[] phoneNos= {"07064267499","07064267499","07064267499"};
```

from :

```
ArrayList<Object> phoneNos = [0803406914, 08167337499, 0803377973] ;
```

This is my code snippet :

```
public ArrayList < Object > getPhoneNo() {
    ArrayList < Object > phoneNos = new ArrayList < Object > ();
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Phone_No FROM paient_details");
        while (result.next()) {
            phoneNos.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return phoneNos;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at Guava's transform list, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383624/how-to-transform-listx-to-another-listy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toArray()` method from your `List` object :

```
String[] phoneNosArray = new String[phoneNos.size()];
phoneNosArray = phoneNos.toArray(phoneNosArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change your `ArrayList` to :

```
ArrayList<String> phoneNos = new ArrayList<String>();
```

since you store `String`s in it.

Then you can get the corresponding array with :

```
String[] arr = phoneNos.toArray(new String[phoneNos.size()]);
```

Comment: @awomtm What do you mean by that? What null was returned? Where?

Comment: return arr; gives null. I am a java newbie anyway.

Comment: @awomtm Can you show the actual code giving the error?

Comment: Add comment says my code is too long. Pls is there any other way to repost my code

Comment: @awomtm You can edit your question and post it there.