# "WHERE IN" statement using greendao Android ORM

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, greendao

I am using greendao to work with sqlite database in my app.
I need to have such feature as `where in` condition
I am looking for such method  or any other possible ways ,but without using raw query.

I need to perform such queries `SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_company IN (SELECT id FROM company WHERE state=1`.

Please suggest what is the best way to perform such query using `GreenDAO` ORM.

Comment: Here's the solution in the official documentation: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Raw_queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Lists.transform()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) from **Guava** as described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383831/3469686)

```
List<Company> companies = session.getCompanyDao()
                           .queryBuilder()
                           .where(CompanyDao.properties.state.eq(1))
                           .list();

Function<Company, Integer> companyToId = new Function<Company,Integer>() { 
    public String apply(Company c) { return c.getId(); }
};

List<Integer> ids = Lists.transform(companies, compnayToId);


session.getNewsDao()
.queryBuilder()
.where(NewsDao.Properties.id_company.in(ids))
.list();
```