# Short way to create sub-list in java

Tags: java, list

Is there a shorter way to create sublist from other list?
For example:
I have a `Contact` obiect, this obiect contain `String` field of `adres`

```
public List<String> getAdreses(long personID) {
        List<String> adreses=null;
        for(Contact mail : getContacts(personID)){
            adreses.add(mail.getMail());
        }
        return adreses;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform List<X> to another List<Y>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383624/how-to-transform-listx-to-another-listy)

Comment: @smoke, your code will not run as it is...

You have initialized adreses list like...
List<String>adreses = null;

and later you are adding element to it like: adreses.add(mail.getMail());

But as you have not initialized adreses like: List<String> adreses=new ArrayList<>();

It will throw NullPointerException...

Answer (score 4):

Try Java [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
List<String> adreses = getContacts(personID).stream().map(Contact::getMail).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: ok, but how can i set value? in this:     .map(Contact::getMail)

Comment: @smok, `.map(Contact::getMail) ` is equal to `.map(contact -> contact.getMail())` and it will **collect** the **mails** to `List`, you don't need to set value.