# Recursively delete all sublists in a list

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, tree

I have a `Node` class. It has a `children` ArrayList. That list consists of Nodes as well. And said nodes have children lists, and so on.

Basically, it's a tree in somewhat not so convenient form. Let's say I want to delete some`Node` from it.  So how to clear all of the child lists recursively?

I have a `hasChildren()` method, which returns if specified node has children, I think it has to help me, but can't figure out how yet. I've also got `getChildren()` method which returns list of children.

Here's some of my code, but it is wrong all over the place.

```
    public void removeChild()
    {
        while(hasChildren())
        {
            getChildren();
            removeChild();            
        }

    children.clear();
}
```

Comment: if you have a method to return first child you can use this solution which is recursive. `public static void removeChilds(Node node) {
    while (node.hasChildren())
        node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild());
}`

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but might answer your question anyway - [How can I call a method on each element of a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221833/how-can-i-call-a-method-on-each-element-of-a-list) Also, `if (hasChildren())`, not `while (hasChildren())`, not that you should really need that because any solution in the above link should work just fine on an empty list.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu What do you mean by first child? Isn't `node.getChildren.get(0)` going to work in that case? That'll only remove all the first-level children, am I wrong?

Comment: Also, if you just remove references to your class or clear the first level, the rest will get cleared by the garbage collector (or is this an assignment you must do?).

Comment: @VadimShmyrov suppose you are correct.let me modify the solution.

Comment: You don't need to clear any sublist recursively at all. Just remove the target node once you find it, and the garbage collector will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `Queue` which you can use to put every Node's children and then pop from it to remove them.

Something like this.

```
Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add(node); //node to remove
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
 Node currentNode = queue.pop();
 for(Node n : currentNode.getChildren) {
    queue.add(n);
 {
 currentNode.getChildren.clear();
}
```

UPDATE: To do it recursively you could implement something like this (just be aware of stack size in java).

```
public void removeChildren(Node node)
{
   for(Node n : node.getChildren()) {
      removeChildren(n);            
   }
   node.getChildren().clear();
}
```

Comment: I suggest `ArrayDeque` for the queue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you just need to clear the children (as shown below) and the Garbage collector will automatically free rest of the objects.

```
public void removeChild()
{
    if(hasChildren())
    { 
      children.clear();  
    }
}
```