# How to set same function property for multiple variable?

Tags: java

I was searching for a shortcut to set same property function to multiple variables.

I am trying to achieve something like `{var1, var2, var3}.setSomething(true)` and `(var1, var2, var3).setSomething(true)` but it is not working. Is there anyway to get this done?

instead of

```
var1.setSomething(true)
var2.setSomething(true)
var3.setSomething(true)
```

How can I write all these in a same line or setting it only once?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221833/how-can-i-call-a-method-on-each-element-of-a-list) for a way to do this using a collection with streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

old school way, write a helper function:

```
public static void setSomeThing(boolean value, Target ... targets){
    if(targets == null)
        return;

    for(Target target : targets){
        target.setSomeThing(value);
    }
}
```

for using:

```
setSomeThing(true,var1,var2,var3);
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for